# Problems with setters and getters in java program dealing with circles

Tags: java, geometry, getter, setter

I have been assigned the following task for an introductory java course:

You should write a class that represents a circle object and includes the following:

1. Private class variables that store the radius and centre coordinates of the object.
2. Constructors to create circle objects with nothing supplied, with just a radius value supplied and with a radius and centre coordinates supplied.
3. Public instance methods that allow the radius and centre coordinates to be set and retrieved (often known as set/get methods).
4. Public instance methods that return the circumference and area of the circle.
5. A public class method that tests if two circle objects overlap or not

Here is my code:

```
import java.lang.Math;
public class Circle {
private double xCentre, yCentre, Radius;
//    constructors
public Circle() {                      
xCentre = 0.0;
yCentre = 0.0;
Radius = 1.0;
}
public Circle(double R) {                      
xCentre = 0.0;
yCentre = 0.0;
Radius = R;
}

public Circle(double x, double y, double R) {
   xCentre = x;
   yCentre = y;
    Radius = R;
}

//getters

public double getX() {     
return xCentre;
}
public double getY() {
return yCentre;
}
public double getRadius() {   
return Radius;
}
//setters
public void setX(double NewX) {
xCentre = NewX;
}
public void setY(double NewY) {
yCentre = NewY;
}
public void setRadius(double NewR) {
Radius = NewR;
}

//calculate circumference and area
public double Circumference() {
return 2*Math.PI*Radius;
}
public double Area() {
return Math.PI*Radius*Radius;
}

//determine overlap
public static double Overlap(Circle c1, Circle c2) {
double xDelta = c1.getX() - c2.getX();
double yDelta = c1.getY() - c2.getY();
double separation = Math.sqrt(xDelta*xDelta + yDelta*yDelta);
double radii = c1.getRadius() + c2.getRadius();
return separation - radii;
}
}
}
```

and

```
import java.io.Console;

public class cp6 {
public static void main(String args[]){

//Set up the Console
       Console myConsole = System.console();
       //Declare cirlce
Circle first = new Circle(2.0,4.0,6.0);

myConsole.printf("Circumference of first circle is ", first.Circumference(), "\n");
myConsole.printf("Area of first circle is ", first.Circumference(), "/n");

first.setRadius(2);
first.setX(2);
first.setY(2);

myConsole.printf("New X of first circle is ", first.getX(), "/n");
myConsole.printf("New Y of first circle is ", first.getY(), "/n");
myConsole.printf("New Radius of first circle is ", first.getRadius(), "/n");

Circle second = new Circle(-1.0,3.0,5.0);
Circle third = new Circle(1,1,1);

if (Circle.Overlap(second, third) <= 0) {
    myConsole.printf("Second and third circles overlap");
}
else {
    myConsole.printf("Second and third circles do not overlap");
}

    myConsole.printf("New Y of first circle is ", first.getY());

   Calculate and print out distance between them using the class method

myConsole.printf("Distance between first and second is : %.5g\n", Circle.Overlap(first, second));
}
}
```

The second program just has to demonstrate each aspect addressed in the brief I pasted at the top and I've only a rough idea of how to do this so if what I'm doing seems stupid to any of you please offer suggestions of what else I can do.

Comment: James, I'd love to help you. But after reading all of that twice, I still don't really understand what exactly you need help with. Ask a clearer question and I'll answer it.

Comment: @AlexK: I translate the question as, "here's my requirements, here's some code that's not working, I have no idea what's wrong". To the OP, I recommend that you remove your apology and instead show what comes from your attempts to debug your code. Use a debugger or println statements, but first you must find what is wrong and have a specific before you can come here.

Comment: All I was able to do during my lab session was write this code, email it to myself and recall from memory anything else. The problem is that when this code runs it doesn't display any numerical values, ie nothing is being passed between the two programs. I'm sorry I can't be clearer but I really have exhausted my limited ability to explain what's going on. If you could even just give general suggestion for why this might be it really would help me a lot. Please don't down vote this when I haven't knowingly done anything wrong. I'm desperate for any help and would be extremely appreciative.

Comment: Try changing the name of the method to getCircum()

Comment: Honestly I don't know. To me, that looks right

Comment: Thanks so much Alex K, I will try that tomorrow but until then there's nothing I can really do. Hopefully it'll go some way to getting it working.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're using the `Console.printf()` method incorrectly.

The first parameter to this method should be a format, and it has to have placeholders inside it for the other parameters. Read up on it in [The Java Platform documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-). In fact, you should familiarize yourself with the Java platform documentation. You need to use it often to make sure you're calling methods correctly or what methods are available in a given class.

So, your printout lines should actually have been:

```
myConsole.printf("Circumference of first circle is %.2f%n", first.Circumference());
myConsole.printf("Area of first circle is %.2f%n", first.Area());
```

...etc.

The format `%.2f` means "The corresponding parameter is a floating-point number. Display it with a precision of 2 digits after the decimal point". The `%n` replaces your `"\n"` - the whole "template" of the print should be just in the format string. And in this type of format, one should use `%n` instead of `\n`.

I'm not sure why you opted for using the system console rather than the usual `System.out.println()`. If you choose to go with `System.out`, there is also a `printf()` method there that works exactly as `Console.printf()` - the first parameter is a format, the others are embedded in it.

One last comment: there are conventions when writing Java code:

- Indent your code properly
- Class names' first letter is always uppercase.
- Non-constant fields and local variable names' first letter is always lowercase.
- Method names also start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thanks so much RealSkeptic, I appreciate your help doubly as I am aware I didn't make it easy to understand the problem (because I couldn't), I'll adjust my code, test it tomorrow and pray to god it works!